# variable IFS and different result with listing files with loop

Tags: bash, find, wildcards

I want to get list of files in current directory and its sub-directories (I want to use one-liner script):

```
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b");
for FILE in $(find -type f); do echo "$FILE"; done
```

Usually, it works as expected, but recently, with my list of files:

> file_.doc
>   file_0.doc
>   file_[2006_02_25].doc
>   file_[2016_06_16].odt
>   file_[2016_06_16].pdf
>   file_[16-6-2006].doc
>   file_.pdf
>   file_ 4-4-2006.doc

the output is:

```
./file_.doc                                                                                                                                                 
./file_0.doc                                                                                                                                                
./file_0.doc
./file_[2016_06_16].odt
./file_[2016_06_16].pdf
./file_0.doc
./file_.pdf
./file_ 4-4-2006.doc
```

If I change the variable IFS to:

```
IFS=$(echo -en "\n");
```

then the output will be (corrected):

```
./file_.doc
./file_0.doc
./file_[2006_02_25].doc
./file_[2016_06_16].odt
./file_[2016_06_16].pdf
./file_[16-6-2006].doc
./file_.pdf
./file_ 4-4-2006.doc
```

I have read that `'\b'` is [neccesary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16831429/when-setting-ifs-to-split-on-newlines-why-is-it-necessary-to-include-a-backspac), and found a solution that [using `printf`, instead of `echo`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26157072).

My questions are:

1) Could you explain what made those outputs different?

2) A solution using `printf` above could be an alternative to `echo -en "\n\b"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output of a command substitution is subject to word splitting (which you took care of by setting `IFS`), *and* filename globbing. The `[abc]` construct is the "match any of the characters `a`, `b`, `c`" as usual, and
`[2006_02_25].doc` matches `0.doc`.

---

In Bash/ksh/zsh, you can use the double-star to get all files in the directory tree (recursively, not just the current directory). This should find the same files as your example:

```
shopt -s globstar      # in Bash
# set -o globstar      # in ksh
for file in **/* ; do
    [[ -f $file ]] || continue     # check it's a regular file, like find -type f
    ...
done
```

---

Of course, `find` *is* powerful, so using it might be easier if you have lots of conditions. If you do, you should disable filename globbing with `set -f` in addition to fixing `IFS`:

```
set -f
IFS=$'\n'
for file in $(find -type f -some -other -conditions) ; do
    ...
done
```

or use a `while read` loop with process substitution instead:

```
while IFS= read -r file ; do 
    ...
done < <(find -type f -some -other -conditions)
```

<sub>(The above is similar to `find ... | while ...`, but it bypasses the issue of the last part of a pipeline being executed in a subshell.)</sub>

Both of those assume the filenames don't contain newlines, as they're used as the separator for the output of `find`. <sub>(and because `$(..)` eats final newlines.)</sub>

In Bash, at least, there's actually a way to make newlines in filenames work too. Setting the `read` delimiter to the empty string makes it effectively use the NUL byte as delimiter. So:

```
while IFS= read -d '' -r file ; do 
    ...
done < <(find -type f -some -other -conditions -print0)
```

Though that's starting to get icky to write, as you do need all those options to `read` to make it work without mangling the input.

---

As for the `IFS`... Setting `IFS=$(echo -en "\n");` sets `IFS` to the empty string (because command substitution eats the trailing newline), resulting in *no* splitting. The output in this case seems correct since you get all the output of `find` in one go, not line-by-line. This also masks the issue with filename globbing, since the full, multiline string doesn't match any filenames and is passed as-is.

You can see the difference if you do anything else than just print the loop value. Try adding some separators:

```
IFS=$(echo -en "\n")       # same as IFS=
for FILE in $(find -type f); do echo "<$FILE>"; done
```

By far the easiest way to set `IFS` to a newline in anything but the barest standard shells is `IFS=$'\n'`.

Comment: Very detailed explanation!

Answer (score 4):

Don't do `$( find ... )`. It will invoke filename generation (globbing), and some of your filenames will be interpreted as globbing patterns that matches other filenames.  For example, the pattern `file_[2006_02_25].doc` and `file_[16-6-2006].doc` matches `file_0.doc` which is why this filename occurs instead of these two patterns.

Your loop will furthermore not start iterating until the `find` command in the command substitution has generated all its pathnames, which could in the general case use up quite an amount of memory, and is not really *elegant*.

Instead, just use `find` (and don't modify `IFS`):

```
find . type -f -print
```

If you want to do other things with these files, then you may do so in an `-exec`:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'printf "Found the file %s\n" "$@"' sh {} +
```

If you just want to process the files in the current directory, you may simply

```
for name in *; do
    printf 'Found the name %s\n' "$name"
done
```

Related:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)

Comment: For recursively get files inside subdirectories (I want to get files' name as variables), I manage to use loop with testing if the entries are directory, and go inside each directories, I could do this, but I want to know if it is "safe"? Thanks!

Comment: @duqu You could do that (if you always remember to quote variable expansions), but it's awkward. It would be better if you used `-exec` to execute the needed code on each file, or group of files.  I wasn't able to write anything more specific about this, because the question is not about how to do that but about why you get different results with your code.